# Checking for existing SSH keys using Git Bash

Tags: github, repository, ssh-keys

I would like to use a SSH key for creating a GitHub repository.

For further information I followed this guide:
[Checking for existing ssh keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys)

After using the command `ls -al ~/.ssh` I get following results:

[image]

What does that mean? Do I have already a ssh key or not?

This is not clear to me.

Under paragraph "Checking for existing SSH keys" from the GitHub site
they write:

[image]

I cannot see any filenames.

Please tell me what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Qais87

Comment: A SSH key can be located anywhere, `~/.ssh` is just the default (and therefore most common) place to store them. You don't have any SSH key in this folder. If you did, you would see pairs of files with similar names, like "id_rsa" and id_rsa.pub" (the first one being the private key, and the second one the public key that Github wants).